How to execute a .purge command in ADX using Azure Data Factory?
Approach 1
Created an ADX activity in ADF, and in the command field, I wrote the purge command (which I copied from Azure Docs):
.purge table MyTable in database DBName allrecords
I tried running the purge command but it keeps returning syntax error: BadRequest_SyntaxError: Request is invalid and cannot be executed
Approach 2
Created a Web Activity in ADF, where I used a Linked Service, and set the following config:
Base URL as the URI of the Kusto cluster: https://<clusterName>.<region>.kusto.windows.net
Authentication: System Assigned Managed Identity
Resource: https://<clusterName>.<region>.kusto.windows.net (URI of the Kusto cluster)
Relative URL: v1/rest/mgmt
Method: POST
Body:
{
    "db": "DBName",
    "csl": ".purge table MyTable in database DBName allrecords"
}

But it also returns the same error: BadRequest_SyntaxError: Request is invalid and cannot be executed
The user/role has Admin privileges to the cluster and Purge is enabled from the ADX Config.
Note that I'm not using the ingest- endpoint here to run purge because I couldn't get it to work and there isn't info available in the docs as to where to put the ingest- endpoint URL.

it sounds like you're using the wrong URL/endpoint - as mentioned in the documentation: "Purge execution is invoked by running purge table TableName records command on the Data Management endpoint https://ingest-[YourClusterName].[Region].kusto.windows.net."

How exactly does it work? There is no way to configure that in ADX Activity.
And for that to work in Web Activity in ADF, where do I need to put the ingest endpoint? In the base URL? What should be the relative URL?

if the tool you've chosen (e.g., ADF) doesn't allow you to configure/execute the flow you need to (e.g., cause it only supports a specific type of endpoint which isn't the one you need), then you should consider using a different tool (examples are provided here, for instance Power Apps, Power Automate, Azure Functions, Logic Apps)

As I said, I tried to use Web Activity which technically should support this. But it's still giving the same error
